# Setting and modifying a change event on a feature in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, features

I created an onChange feature event and each time I drag the feature over the map, it console.log its properties.

```
var newFeature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(e_coordinate),
   property: 1
});
newFeature.setId(33);
source.addFeature(newFeature);
```

I change the property as follows

```
source.getFeatureById(33).values_.property=2
```

And if I console.log the property I get 2, which is correct

Finally I add the on change event on the feature

```
newFeature.on('change',
  function () {
    try {
         console.log("on change props -->" + props);
    } catch (error) {
         alert('feature on change error 2\n' + error);
    }
  },
  newFeature
);
```

The problem appears when I drag the feature over the map. It keeps logging the previous value (1) and not the latest one (2). Is there any way to reset the new property some how inside the on change event?

Am I missing something?

Comment: First, you don't change values by modifying internal feature property `.values_`. Internal OL properties should never be modifed directly. The correct way is by using `.set` method: `source.getFeatureById(33).set('property', 2)`. Second, third parameter `newFeature` in setting `change` event processing function has no meaning, method `.on` accepts only two parameters. Third, what do you mean by "keeps logging the previous value"? What is `props`? Where is it defined? When does it change?

Comment: Hi TomazicM and R.Martin! Thanks for your comments. I totaly forgot to add the props variable! The  props is a variable that holds the contents of the feature properties. var props=source.getFeatures()[1].values_.properties. I change it from the browser console with the anorthodox mentioned way, just to figure out if the problem ensist. Just to mention, the code has being changed. (:

Comment: So you understand now what you have to change in your code?

Comment: Yes, but the posted snapshot of this code has been totaly removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Features properties are useally a key-value pair ( {color : 'red'}) and  modifications can be made with setProperties method

```
var newFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(e_coordinate),
  property: {custom_val : 1}
 });
```

And modifying properties :

```
source.getFeatureById(33).setProperties({custom_val:2});
```